# Count number of repeated elements in list considering the ones larger than them

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy

I am trying to do some clustering analysis on a dataset. I am using a number of different approaches to estimate the number of clusters, then I put what every approach gives (number of clusters) in a list, like so:

```
total_pred =  [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

Now I want to estimate the real number of clusters, so I let the methods above vote, for example, above, more models found 1 cluster than 0, so I take 1 as the real number of clusters.

I do this by:

```
    counts = np.bincount(np.array(total_pred))
    real_nr_of_clusters = np.argmax(counts))
```

There is a problem with this method, however. If the above list contains something like:

```
[2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

I will get 0 clusters as the average, since 0 is repeated more often. However, if one model found 2 clusters, it's safe to assume it considers at least 1 cluster is there, hence the real number would be 1.

How can I do this by modifying the above snippet?

To make the problem clear, here are a few more examples:

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3]
```

should return 1,

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4]
```

should also return 1 (since most of them agree there is AT LEAST 1 cluster).

Comment: I am lost at : `I will get 0 clusters as the average, since 0 is repeated more often. However, if one model found 2 clusters, it's safe to assume it considers at least 1 cluster is there, hence the real number would be 1.`, specifically the second sentence. Clarify?

Comment: We have a basket with apples. We take 20 people and tell them to count the apples. Some will say 1, some will say 2 (in equal number) and two people say 6 and 9. The people who say 6 and 9, even though they are way off, both would agree that there are at least 2 apples there (since they believe there are much more), so the correct vote average here is 2.

Comment: There is a logical problem with your condition. Your condition=> (how many clusters have x or more). For the last list it is {0:7, 1:4, 3:2, 4:1}, so 0 clusters is the best. This logic always results in the smallest number of clusters.

Comment: The people who say that there are 2 apples, also agree that there are at least one apple. So, why shouldn't the output be 1? How is that *average* coming in here?

Comment: What would be the output of `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]`?

Comment: If I am understanding the problem, you are looking for the 'mode' of the list (the value that is repeated most often) and the problem is that when you have 2 or more values that repeat the same number of times your logic doesn't tell you there is a mode because there are multiple. Is that correct?

Comment: @IliaL that is not correct, if he only wanted the mode `numpy.unique(return_counts=True)` would be all he needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## There is a problem with your logic

Here is an implementation of the described algorithm.

```
l = [2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

l = sorted(l, reverse=True)

votes = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(l, start=1)}
```

### Output

```
{2: 1, 1: 5, 0: 9}
```

Notice that since you define a vote as agreeing with anything smaller than itself, then `min(l)` will *always* win, because everyone will agree that there are at least `min(l)` clusters. In this case `min(l) == 0`.

## How to fix it

### Mean and median

Beforehand, notice that taking the mean or the median are valid and light-weight options that both satisfy the desired output on your examples.

### Bias

Although, taking the mean might not be what you want if, for say, you encounter votes with high variance such as `[0, 0, 7, 8, 10]` where it is unlikely that the answer is `5`.

A more general way to fix that is to include a voter's bias toward votes close to theirs. Surely that a 2-voter will agree more to a `1` than a `0`.

You do that by implementing a metric (note: this is not a metric in the mathematical sense) that determines how much an instance that voted for `x` is willing to agree to a vote for `y` on a scale of `0` to `1`.

Note that this approach will allow voters to agree on a number that is not on the list.

We need to update our code to account for applying that pseudometric.

```
def d(x, y):
    return x <= y

l = [2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

votes = {y: sum(d(x, y) for x in l) for y in range(min(l), max(l) + 1)}
```

#### Output

```
{0: 9, 1: 5, 2: 1}
```

The above metric is a sanity check. It is the one your provided in your question and it indeed ends up determining that `0` wins.

### Metric choices

You will have to toy a bit with your metrics, but here are a few which may make sense.

#### Inverse of the linear distance

```
def d(x, y):
    return 1 / (1 + abs(x - y))

l = [2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

votes = {y: sum(d(x, y) for x in l) for y in range(min(l), max(l) + 1)}
# {0: 6.33, 1: 6.5, 2: 4.33}
```

#### Inverse of the *nth* power of the distance

This one is a generalization of the previous. As `n` grows, voters tend to agree less and less with distant vote casts.

```
def d(x, y, n=1):
    return 1 / (1 + abs(x - y)) ** n

l = [2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

votes = {y: sum(d(x, y, n=2) for x in l) for y in range(min(l), max(l) + 1)}
# {0: 5.11, 1: 5.25, 2: 2.44}
```

#### Upper-bound distance

Similar to the previous metric, this one is close to what you described at first in the sense that a voter will never agree to a vote higher than theirs.

```
def d(x, y, n=1):
    return 1 / (1 + abs(x - y)) ** n if x >= y else 0

l = [2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

votes = {y: sum(d(x, y, n=2) for x in l) for y in range(min(l), max(l) + 1)}
# {0: 5.11, 1: 4.25, 2: 1.0}
```

#### Normal distribution

An other option that would be sensical is a [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) or a [skewed normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution).

Comment: This is a very informative and complete answer. Thank you so much, now I understand why there was a logic fault with my proposal.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answer provides a comprehensive review of possible metrics and methods, it seems what you are seeking is to find the closest number of clusters to mean!
So something as simple as:

`cluster_num=int(np.round(np.mean(total_pred)))`

Which returns 1 for all your cases as you expect.